# import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved

Tags: java, import, java-package

Well, my problem is about cannot import java.util.Arrays package. I use eclipse kepler and the latest version of jdk. I added JRE System Library (jdk1.8.0_144).And also I use jdk1.8.0_144 as an installed jre. When ı want to import this package, it cannnot be resolved. Formerly, I met with this problem but a guy said that you should change your eclipse type. At that time, I was using eclipse indigo and he suggested using eclipse kepler. I definitely do not understand the problem.

Comment: `java.util.Arrays` is not a package but a class. Import problems might arise from problems with your project setup so have a look there, e.g. if you're using a build framework such as Maven, the dependencies might not be resolved correctly. If you don't find anything try at least refreshing and cleaning everything. - That assumes you're doing the import correctly though, so please check that first.

Comment: eclipse kepler is *ancient*. The current version is *oxygen*, and there were *luna*, *mars* and *neon* in the interim.

Comment: @Thomas I have removed everything. Then, again I met same problem. I am not sure but I think I should change the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Project Building..?
Please Check if the build path is set correct or not.
If not, then change that.

Right Click on Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path

Comment: How can I make sure that builth path is set correct or not?